# Java-EE Session Clarification

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a web-application in java which is invoked by yet another web-application written i java.
My concern is about the session timeout.
Say if the session timeout for the web-application being invoked is 30 mins for user session timeout and the session timeout for the web-application which invokes the web-application is 15 mins.

What would be the session timeout value for the web application for the website being invoked either 30 mins as set in its own web.xml or 15 mins as set in the web-application which invokes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have web-app A which is invoked by web-app B.

A has a session timeout of 30 minutes.

B has a session timeout of 15 minutes.

And you're asking what the session timeout of A is.

Well, the answer is in the question: 30 minutes. Whether A receives HTTP requests from a regular user or from another web application is irrelevant.